# OS Linux in windows

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system

I want to learn to use the Linux system, and I own a Windows machine. When I searched for a way to install Linux on Windows, I found two methods. The first is to download the Linux system through Microsoftstore, and the second method is to use the VirtualBox program.I would like to know which of the two methods is better and safer for my device?

I'm still searching for an answer on Google, but I haven't found any direct answer

Comment: Both are good. So is a third option - dual booting a second operating system side by side with windows. This question will end up closed however - as it's basically a matter of opinion (or at least various arguments can be made as to pros and cons) and this is a site for specific programming related problems, not a place to get advice. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic I'd recommend you do a little bit of research then stop worrying - just make a choice and starting learning.

Comment: Safest is to delete Windows and just run Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), see the official documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Also for sure the virtual machine option is a safe option for your machine as this is the essence of VMs, they are type of isolation of the environment, so you can use the free options provided by VMware.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are possible, there are other ways, but if you searched and didn't find an answer, I must say that you probably didn't search well, because it's a simple issue, because your question is unanswered, for example, I think using virtual box is for you who have less knowledge about Linux It is better and probably causes less problems

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version of Windows; is it Windows 10 or 11, or earlier, or a version of Windows Server?  I'll assume it's a non-server version, at least Windows 10.

I'll expand on the existing answers and add some of my own...

Virtualization allows you to experience a full Linux system: installation, graphical desktop, etc.  I think that the following are the four easiest choices.  None has limitations that affect your use case.

- Microsoft's built-in virtualization tool "Hyper-V"

  - easiest to install, just enable the Windows feature
  - You must add yourself to the "Hyper-V Administrators" group or you won't be able to use the Hyper-V management tool.
- VMware Player

  - free for personal use
  - download and install are straightforward
- VMware Workstation

  - US $200 to get VM snapshots, cloning, etc.
  - download and install are straightforward
- VirtualBox

  - free for personal use
  - download and install are straightforward
  - Use can be a bit finicky, eg. due to how installation media (ISO files) are handled, but it's all documented.

Windows Subsystem for Linux: note that it requires Windows 10 version 2004 and higher (Build 19041 and higher).

- This may help you to learn to use Linux *tools*, but isn't the best choice if trying to learn about Linux *systems*.

Containers: you can run a Linux container under Windows 10: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-10-linux.

- Here too, you can use Linux *tools*, but this isn't a Linux *system*.
- Note that the example provided in the quick start guide isn't the best; you'll want a more featureful Docker image, such as for Oracle Linux, Arch Linux, Ubuntu, Fedora etc.

Dual booting: if you go that route, use separate media, rather than installing on your current storage.

- You can boot from a "live bootable" Linux distribution DVD such as Ubuntu; this lets you experiment without modifying your Windows system.
- Such live bootable images can also be written to a USB stick for a much more responsive experience.

Lastly, this Microsoft article may also help you choose the best solution for your use case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linux/install

--klode